# Strongly monotone, Lipschitz continuous and contractivity

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization

Let $(V,||.||)$ be a Hilbert space and the operator $T:V \rightarrow V$, strongly monotone and Lipschitz continuous, specifically it satisfies:
$$ (T(v_1)-T(v_2),v_1-v_2)\ge c_1 ||v_1-v_2||^2,$$
$$ ||T(v_1)-T(v_2)||\le c_2||v_1-v_2||,$$
with $c_1,c_2>0$ and $v_1,v_2 \in V$.
Now given $b\in V$ we define the operator $T_\theta: V \rightarrow V$ by
$$T_\theta(v)=v-\theta(T(v)-b),$$
where $\theta\neq0$.
I want to show that for $\theta \in (0,2c_1/c_2^2)$ the operator $T_\theta$ is a contraction. I have tried several times but I can not get the requested upper bound for $\theta$.

Comment: Is $V$ a HIlbert space? Or what does the pairing $(\cdot, \cdot )$ in the first line denote?

Comment: Yes $V$ is a Hilbert space and $(.,.)$ is the inner product. Sorry forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the Pythagorean Theorem we have,

$$
\begin{split}
\| T_\theta(v)-T_\theta(w)\|^2 & = \| v-w\|^2 -2\theta(T(v)-T(w), v-w) + \theta^2\| T(v)-T(w)\| \\
& \leq \left( 1- 2\theta c_1 + \theta^2c_2^2\right)\| v-w\|^2.
\end{split}
$$

Therefore, it's enough to show that $\theta^2c_2^2-2\theta c_1<0$. This is exactly your condition on $\theta$.

Comment: Thank you for the help!